# Jenkins Pipeline - Set process.env variable from build parameter

Tags: jenkins

In my Jenkins feature file I have set a build parameter using:

```
  parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1xxx/",
              description: 'Which environment to run on',
              name: 'Environment')
    }
```

Initially, I attempted to use the `environment` block to set this as a `process.env` variable however realised that I can't access it using the standard `${params.Environment}`.

So i found it can be accessed in the steps/script block however how do I set it a process.env variable so that my code can see it:

```
steps {
        script {
          //def process.env.MYENVTEST = "${params.Environment}"
          ...
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

things defined in the `environment` block can be accessed elsewhere in the Jenkinsfile via `env.MY_VAR` (like `echo env.MY_VAR`).

things defined in the `parameters` block can be accessed elsewhere in the Jenkinsfile via `params.MY_OTHER_VAR`.

both can be accessed in scripts called by the Jenkinsfile as environment variables. it sounds like you're using node-based scripts and that you had better luck with the `environment` block for some reason. i'd probably just use that and, if you need to, refer to your variables via `env.THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_VAR`.